# How can I pass a formatted string to a javascript var? see c# example what I mean

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net

Using this is very helpful when trying to generate html code in c#.

```
            var someString = @"
            <html>
                <body>
                    Some html
                </body>
            </html>";
```

I know of the Html library to add elements in form of objects but I don't use that. The question is how to do the same thing in javascript?

Comment: Is this a question about javascript templating?

Comment: Do you mean a multiline string? Using \n is the sane response. You can actually just end a line with \ to have the browser continue the string literal to the next line, but this won't pass JSLint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that but you can do this...

```
<script type="text/html" id="somestring">
  your string blah blah blah
  blah blah blah
</script>
<script>
  var mystring = document.getElementById('somestring').innerHTML;
</script>
```

Comment: interesting... jquery= $("#somestring").html() is fine also, I suppose

Comment: Yes, I prefer jQuery but just showing without the need of jQuery.

Comment: EJS for templating uses AJAX for remote templates out of the box. I really like it as you can also use JavaScript syntax without having to learn some strange abstraction like handlebars.

Comment: worked wonderfully, for the records, accessing jquery content = $("#somestring").text(), asnwer accepted, thanks

Comment: also, just to note, processing.js takes this concept light years ahead and interprets the script area as Java syntax and also coffee script uses this same concept. take this further and make a razor syntax parser. man. be a trend setter.

Comment: ..wow, you learn something new every day. Thanks for that! +1.